# Finding records for founding of printing firm of Messrs. Hughes and Son, Ltd. at Becon, Wales around 1802

Tags: wales, 1800s-decade, breconshire

A Roger_Heron shared the [image](https://www.ancestry.com.au/mediaui-viewer/collection/1030/tree/32456697/person/28451184697/media/23af6818-1501-4f1d-90e2-319963e6a9ff?_phsrc=XcZ33135&usePUBJs=true) (needs subscription to view) that the picture below is cut from on 16 Jan 2020 at Ancestry.com:

[image]

The text in the picture is (with my bolding):

> The **printing firm of Messrs. Hughes and Son, Ltd.**, was a family
>   business who brought their employees into the family circle.  The
>   photograph below was taken in January 1952 at the Clarence Hotel on
>   the occasion of a threefold celebration: first to pay tribute to the
>   239 years combined service record achieved by four employees of the
>   Griffin Press, Messrs. Edwin Adey, Oliver Williams William Thomas, and
>   Frank Lewis; secondly to mark **the firm's 150 years since it was
>   founded in Brecon**; and thirdly to recognise the firm's 100 years of
>   progress in Pontypool.

This is of interest to me because 150 years before 1952, in 1802, my 4th great grandfather Henry John Hughes (1780-1820) was a printer in Brecon and his grandson (my 1st cousin 4 x removed) moved the business to Pontypool in 1877.

Where might I be able to find records of the founding of the "printing firm of Messrs. Hughes and Son, Ltd." in about 1802 which might enlighten me further about the life of Henry John Hughes (1780-1820), and his immediate family?

I have no idea what the process of registering a company name would have been in Wales at that time.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest two avenues of exploration:

1. Newspapers of the period accessed (e.g.) via [The British Newspaper Archive](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/) or (for Wales) via [Welsh Newspapers](https://newspapers.library.wales/) at the National Library of Wales. There may have been news items, advertisments, information about property transactions relevant to the founding of the business...
2. [Powys Archives](https://en.powys.gov.uk/article/1870/Find-archives--local-records) which could hold collections lodged by local businesses (including solicitors).  Founding the business will inevitably have involved some legal transactions which you might find records of at the local archives.